# Convolution layer in keras

Tags: keras

I am exploring convolution layer in keras from:

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L233

everywhere i found following type of code lines:

```
 @interfaces.legacy_conv1d_support
@interfaces.legacy_conv2d_support
```

what is working and role of these lines. I searched in google but not find answer anywhere. please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines starting with `@` are called `decorators` in `python`. Check out [this](https://www.thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/) page to read a brief summary about them. The basic function of this decorators is, that they wrap the following function into another function which has some kind of "wrapper" functions, like preprocessing the arguments, changing the accessibility of the function etc.

Taking a look at the `interfaces.py` file you will see this:

```
legacy_conv1d_support = generate_legacy_interface(
    allowed_positional_args=['filters', 'kernel_size'],
     conversions=[('nb_filter', 'filters'),
                 ('filter_length', 'kernel_size'),
                 ('subsample_length', 'strides'),
                 ('border_mode', 'padding'),
                 ('init', 'kernel_initializer'),
                 ('W_regularizer', 'kernel_regularizer'),
                 ('b_regularizer', 'bias_regularizer'),
                 ('W_constraint', 'kernel_constraint'),
                 ('b_constraint', 'bias_constraint'),
                 ('bias', 'use_bias')],
    preprocessor=conv1d_args_preprocessor)
```

So, the use of this function is basicly to rename parameters. Why is this? The `keras` API changed the names of some arguments of some functions (like `W_regularizer` -> `kernel_regularizer`). To allow users to be able to run old code, they added this decorator, which will just replace the names of old arguments with the corresponding new parameter name before calling the real function. This allows you to run "old" `keras 1` code, even though you have installed `keras 2`.

**Tl;dr**: These lines are just used to for compatibility reasons. As this are just internal aspects of `keras` there is nothing you have to worry about or to take care of.